# How can i solve this second-order differential equation $y^{\prime\prime}=a\sqrt{1+y^{\prime}}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

**My problem** is to solve this given equation: $y^{\prime\prime}=a\sqrt{1+y^{\prime}}$

**My approach** was: But i dont know how to handle $a$ and besides this fact, it is a second-order equation. so i thought i'll have to find out, what's $y^{\prime}$ like. But i don't know.

$$y^{\prime}=\int a\sqrt{1+y^{\prime}}\ dx$$ (or $dy$?)
$$y^{\prime}=a\cdot \int \sqrt{1+y^{\prime}}\ dx$$

I think i could need help in solving this equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote $u=y'$, then
$$u'=a\sqrt{1+u}\;\Longrightarrow\; \int\frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u}}=\int adx.$$
This in turn implies
$$2\sqrt{1+u}=ax+C\;\Longrightarrow\; u=\frac{(ax+C)^2}{4}-1.$$
Recalling that $u=y'$ and integrating once more, we find
$$y=\frac{(ax+C)^3}{12a}-x+D,$$
where $C$, $D$ denote two arbitrary constants of integration.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $y'=z$. Then the equation can be written as $z'=a\sqrt{1+z}$. We recognize this as a **separable** equation that can be solved using standard techniques.

And now that you have $z$, that is, $y'$, you have another first-order equation to solve.

**Added:** For this I really prefer Leibniz notation. So we are looking at 
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=a\sqrt{1+z},$$
which can be written as
$$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+z}}=a\,dx.$$
Integrate. We get 
$$2\sqrt{1+z}=ax+C.$$
Now replace $z$ by $y'$, solve for $y'$, and continue.

Comment: i'll take $z'=a\cdot \sqrt{1+z}$  integrate and get: $$\int z' = \int a\cdot \sqrt{1+z}$$ $$z=\frac{1}{4}\(a^2\cdot x^2+2a\cdot c_1\cdot x+c^{2}_{1}\)$$ ?

Comment: @ToralfWestström No, start by dividing by $\sqrt{1+z}$.